# Using Zend_Log in custom classes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-log

I am using Zend_Log, and other required classes, without the MVC framework.  I want to add Zend's logging capabilities (and other modules in the future) to my custom classes and I am wondering what the best approach is for doing so.

Right now I have a wrapper for the Zend logger so, presumably, I can access it globally:

```
My_log::log('Testing', Zend_Log::INFO);
```

Should I be adding this code to each method in my classes that I want to log?  Should I not create logs inside my classes?  Is there a smarter way?

I appreciate the help,
DC

Comment: The concept of logging is bugging me too, right now. But I have also SOAP calls to logging server to log from many different app instances at one place :(

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection container seems like a great solution if your app can be integrated. All static calls cause issues in testing environment.

have look around this doc
http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/trunk/book/04-Builder

Worst case i would create a static getter like `My_Log::get()->error("message");` the only point is that now you will be able to easily fix the test environemnt to make get return a fake instance. All your My_Log needs is a `setLogger($logger)` which will replace the static instance with a mock or whatever. Any way static calls are bad :/ if possible try to decouple classes so they would depend on as few classes as possible. Even injecting logger manually into your class constructor is a better idea. If you have MVC action plugin or a base controller could provide lazy loading `getLogger()` so your code could do `$this->getLogger()->error('...');`

art